# DataGridView - DataTable - displaying properties

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

( .NET 2.0, System.Windows.FormsDataGridView and DataTable )

I have 1 datagrid connected to 1 datatable.

That datatable contains 1 column: containing objects of my own type "MyObject".
MyObject has a *public* string property "MyProp".

I want to display 1 column in the grid: showing the string values of the property MyProp of the MyObjects in the table.

But I can't seem to get it to work.

Schematically:

- myTable.Column1.Name: "Obj"
- myDataSet contains 1 table: myTable (filled with a few rows)
- myBindingSource.datasource = myDataSet
- myBindingSource.DataMember = myTable
- myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
- in myDataGridView: 1 DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
- tryout 1:

Column.DataPropertyName="Obj" (generated by default)

Displays the result of (overridden) MyObject.ToString()
Not really what I want, this function is in use for logging.

- tryout 2:

GridViewColumn.DataPropertyName="Obj.MyProp"

Doesn't display anything (MyProp's *get* is never called)

- tryout 3:
  Made the MyProp property bindable:

  ```
  [Bindable (BindableSupport.Yes)]
  public string MyProp
  { ...
  ```

  Samesame, not different from tryout 2

**In short:**

GridViewColumn.DataPropertyName doesn't seem to support *drilling further down* into objects in a datatable's column.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Jan

Comment: Why did you choose a datagridview?  Is there to be paging involved?

Comment: Cos thats the default grid component, DataGrid is not in the toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just putting the Obj.MyProp string value into the datatable row. Putting an object into there will require it to be converted into a string representation (Obj.ToString()) which is getting you the output you are seeing.

A datatable is much like a spreadsheet, not like an Array(Of objects). You have to treat it as such,.

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind to immediate properties of the data-source. For `DataTable`, this means columns. Two options leap to mind:

- don't use `DataTable` - just use a `List<MyObject>` or `BindingList<MyObject>`
- (or) override `MyObject.ToString()` to return `MyProp`

The second isn't very flexible - I'd go with the first. After all, what is a 1-column `DataTable` really doing for you?

Comment: i tried using list<myObject> but i became confused in applying it to the nested class... for single level of class it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via OnRowDataBound event.

In the gridview

1. declare an onrowdatabound method
2. use template

In the method:

1. grab object
2. populate or manipulate display as desired

You can also do what you want by using templates instead of default layout.

Comment: I think he's referring to a DataGridView, not a web DataGrid. If memory serves correct, the DGV doesn't have a OnRowDataBound event.